# Better way to check if TimerService ScheduleExpression is stale

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

My EJB application uses TimerService to run different tasks on the schedule.
The schedule is not hard coded and stored in the DB and it allows to use both specific values and wildcards like "*/10".

I want to remove from the DB stale tasks every time the config is reloading, so I need to determine will be the task running in the future or its schedule is outdated.

I could find the only solution - to create a Timer and use the getNextTimeout() method, but it looks ugly to me.

Is there another, more elegant way to do the job, except for writing my own algorithm?

Comment: Do you mean you have your own DB config table that is tracking EJB tasks in addition to the DB table used by the EJB timers itself?  Are you trying to delete entries from your table when the EJB timer expires, or are you trying to cancel EJB timers when your config DB table is updated?  Typically, you would specify the "info" parameter when creating the EJB timer to correlate them with your own data.

Comment: Yes, I have my own DB config, which also contains many task parameters. This DB tables are editable from another web app.